# Loading the pixels of a scaled BufferedImage

Tags: bufferedimage, pixel

I'm trying to scale an image to a different width, and height. Then create a pixel array from the pixels of the scaled image. The problem is I get an error.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

any way I can get the pixels of the new sized image?

here is the code:

```
protected void scaleImage(int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    try {

        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) img.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
        scaledWidth = newWidth;
        scaledHeight = newHeight;
        //re init the pixels
        pixels = new int[scaledWidth * scaledHeight];

        ((BufferedImage) image).getRGB(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, pixels, 0, scaledWidth);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you run into is that `image.getScaledInstance(...)` returns an image, regardless of whether `image` is an `Image` or a `BufferedImage`.

Now, for this reason (and others, mainly performance-related) it is not recommended to use `image.getScaledImage(...)`. See for example [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for more information, and some alternative methods of scaling.

Adapted from your code, you can use:

```
int newWidth, int newHeight; // from method parameters

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

try {
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}

scaledWidth = newWidth;
scaledHeight = newHeight;

//re init the pixels
pixels = new int[scaledWidth * scaledHeight];
image.getRGB(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, pixels, 0, scaledWidth);
```

See the above link for a step-wise alternative, or use a library like [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) for even better results.

If you *really* want to use `getScaledInstace()` even after you read the above link, you can use the `ImageProducer/ImageConsumer` API, to get at the pixels in asynchronous fashion. But the API is old and a little inconvenient to work with.

Comment: The problem is I'm drawing my images by going through a int[] array of pixels, I'm not using the g.drawImage() function. the getScaledImage() would only be called once when resizing, then i save the pixels into an array and won't have to call resize again until i want a new dimension.

Comment: @EvanNudd: Read my code again. You should use `g.drawImage(...)` instead of `Image image = img.getScaledInstance(...)` only to create the scaled version, not to paint your final image. What you do with your pixels afterwards, is completely up to you. I've updated the code to make it clearer... :-)

Comment: PS: You could further optimize your code by using `pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();`. This is safe, as we created the `BufferedImage` using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.